# Java String replace

Tags: java, string, str-replace, apache-stringutils

Lets say I have a string `"aabbccaa"`. Now I want to replace occurrences of `"aa"` in given string by another string. But it should be in following way.

First occurrence of `"aa"` should be replaced by `"1"` and next occurrence of `"aa"` by `"2"` and so on.

So, the result of the string becomes `"1bbcc2"`.

Comment: If i were you, i would create a char array from the string and do it manually.

Comment: That one can do, but I want to Java predefined String functions somehow ....

Comment: I don't think that's possible, will probably have to be a char array and for loop.

Comment: You *could* use the Pattern class to match on aa and keep a counter on matches. However, this will perform worse than simply checking indexOf, and copying the remaining text into a StringBuilder.

Comment: This is looking like 'How many way to cut the cake?'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `replaceFirst()` in a for loop where counter is incrementing...

```
for (int i = 1; string.contains("aa"); i++) {
    string = string.replaceFirst("aa", "" + i);
}
```

Comment: Seems like better to use `StringBuilder` to prevent creation a new `String` each time a pattern found.

Comment: Problem with this one is it's time complexity. This is clearly an `O(n)` problem, but this code searches the string from the beginning every time, even if you know you have already dealt with that section of string. Making it `O(n*r)` where r is the number of replacements to be done.

Comment: @weston yes you are right but the question is simple and the answer is simple. If he/she wants to make it more performancer and complexer that is her/his responsibility :)

Comment: I only comment because as the answer with the most votes, it's more important to point out it's drawbacks.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using the `Matcher`'s [`appendReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)) method:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("aa");
Matcher m = p.matcher("aabbccaahhhaahhhaaahahhahaaakty");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
// Variable "i" serves as a counter. It gets incremented after each replacement.
int i = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, ""+(i++));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

This approach lets you avoid creating multiple string objects ([demo](http://ideone.com/9YPcs9)).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do using Java functions but using a char array and doing it using a lower level of logic would be faster.

```
String s = "aabbccaa";
String target = "aa";
int i = 1;
String newS;

for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
  newS = s.replaceFirst(target, i++);
  j += newS.length - s.length;
  s = newS;
}
```

Comment: curious question, i know this is obviously a time complexity of O(n) due to the for loop, but where did you find the complexity of the java built in functions? Since I am sometimes curious if the way of manually writing something or of using a java built in function is faster.

Comment: The `replaceFirst` method uses Regular Expressions to do its work. While very useful and fancy they do incur a runtime penality. For simple pattern matching it might be faster to do it your self.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution :

```
    public static void main(String[] a) {

        int i = 1;
        String before = "aabbccaabbaabbaa";
        String regex = "aa";

        String after = substitute(i, before, regex);

        System.out.println(after);

    }

    private static String substitute(int i, String before, String regex) {

        String after = before.replaceFirst(regex, Integer.toString(i++));

        while (!before.equals(after)) {

            before = after;
            after = before.replaceFirst(regex, Integer.toString(i++));

        }

        return after;

    }
```

Output :
`1bbcc2bb3bb4`